# Get SPFolder by Folder's Name

Tags: development, folder

I'm working on a web part that gets all the children of a SPFolder.  The catch is I only have the folder's name.  Would this be possible using a CAML query?  If not how could I construct the folder's URL using the name and site absolute URL to use the SPWeb.GetFolder() method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Here is the CAML for getting a folder by its name.  You'll just need to replace [myName] with your folder's name.  The BeginsWith clause is to get "folder" type items.  This will need to be run with the viewscope "Scope=RecursiveAll"

```
<Where>
<And>
<Contains>
  <FieldRef Name='Title'  />
  <Value Type='Text'>[myName]</Value>
  </Contains>
  <BeginsWith>
  <FieldRef Name = 'ContentTypeId' />
  <Value Type = 'ContentTypeId'>0x0120</Value>
  </BeginsWith>
</And>
</Where>
```